# TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value “undefined” for header “x-api-key” error in Nuxt.js CI / CD

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, circleci

I am using Nuxt.js in SSR mode and trying to deploy to FirebaseHosting using CircleCI.
.circleci / config.yml is as follows.

At this time, you are encountering TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "x-api-key" error in yarn generate while running the job of name: build.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.11.0
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: setup credential
          command: echo $CREDENTIAL_ENV | base64 --decode > .env
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: build
          command: yarn build && yarn generate
      - run:
          name: deploy to Firebase Hosting
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy
```

Although it is not in config.yml, to create sitemap and feed in nuxt.config.js, we use "x-api-key" in the request header to request and generate api. I know that may be causing the error, but if I run the exact same code on my local PC (mac), it works fine.

It would be nice if you could give me any information, even if I had something to understand.

[environment]
The version of node is v12.10.0.
"nuxt": "^2.0.0"

Comment: Sounds like this step `echo $CREDENTIAL_ENV | base64 --decode > .env` isn't working correctly. Check the value of `$CREDENTIAL_ENV` in your CI system

Comment: I set base64-encoded values ​​in environment variables in advance, and just decoded them. I entered the CI environment with ssh and checked it, but there was no problem.